# Is it possible to implement group roles by SecurityBundle on Symfony2? (NOT FOSUser)

Tags: symfony, security, roles

One question please.

I'm using the SecurityBundle of Symfony to manage roles. NOT FOSUserBundle!. It's possible to create and manage groups with this bundle?. In case NO, it's possible/easy migrate from SecurityBundle to FOSUserBundle?

Thanks!

Comment: FOSUserBundle is built on top of the SecurityBundle.  So you not really migrating from one to another.  And yes you can add your own role management software.

Comment: It's possible and you will learn a lot implementing it from scratch. But FOSUserBundle is better if you need a quick development with a lot of useful features.

Comment: As long as you are comfortable with beta or development releases and bc breaks.  FOSUserBundle 2.0 has been basically abandoned for the last 5 years or so.  Far better not to rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

Roles are part of Symfony so it is possible (and simple) to create and manage roles (or groups) with SecurityBundle by following the [symfony doc about authorization and roles](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authorization.html#roles). On an other hand you can also easily migrate to FosUserBundle with the dedicated chapter from [Symfony Cookbook](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#main)